# Java - opening URL in internet explorer using java Desktop

Tags: java, swing, internet-explorer, desktop-application, runtime.exec

I want to know if there is a way to open a webpage specifically in internet explorer using the java Desktop utility.  My company uses both firefox and IE, but the url that needs to be open, is only compatible in IE.  So, my java class needs to open that url in IE no matter what the default browser is.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like your Java program should do a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iexplore http://someurl.com")`

Comment: Thank you paulsm4... I will try the code and see how it goes.

Comment: Cool - glad it worked :)  Please "accept" Tudor's response :)

Answer (score 8):

Sure:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iexplore.exe www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: @Tudor: Thanks a lot, I will give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Can you elaborate a bit further? I am far away from being an expert in Java.  I was wondering if you can give me a short code example.  Thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: *"give me a short code example."*  'Give me money'.  No, SO is not a code factory. But make an attempt, show some effort, and I might oblige.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late to answer the question, But still I will try to add my 2 cents.
The question asked is "*How to open URL in internet explorer using java Desktop*"
The below line of code mentioned in previous answer is correct but it will open in IE only if path is set to it. If there is not path set it will not work and throw error
     `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iexplore.exe www.stackoverflow.com");`

To Force Java open Webpae in IE below is the line of code worked for me even though my default browser is Edge and path for IE is "not" set.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe https://carelink.minimed.eu/");
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
//e.g. myURL=www.google.ch
public void openBrowser(String myURL) {

    //open default OS browser
    URI myURI;
    try {
        myURI = new URI(myURL);
        Desktop my = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            System.out.println("[WARNING] NOT SUPPORTED");
        }
        my.browse(myURI);
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't  seem to explain how to guarantee that the IExplorer is used. This question seems to be answered - I don't see any improvement coming with this new answer.